# Insertion deletion updating not happening in MS Access Database using NetBeans

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, netbeans, ucanaccess

after learning a little of Servlets, I tried to make a simple student information system.
The `index.html` code is

```
<html>
    <body bgcolor="AliceBlue">
        <h1 style="text-align: center">Student Information System</h1>
        <form method="get" action="MIS">
         First Name <input type="text" name="FName"/><br><br>
         Last Name <input type="text" name="LName"/><br><br>
         ID <input type="number" name="ID"/><br><br>
         Age <input type="number" name="Age"><br><br>
         <input type="submit" name="Insert" value="Insert">
         <input type="submit" name="Delete" value="Delete">
         <input type="submit" name="Update" value="Update">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here, I'm using three buttons insert,update and delete to perform the respective operations on database.

This is the `MIS.java` code

```
 /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 *
 * @author Gaurav
 */
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/MIS"})
public class MIS extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet MIS</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet MIS at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
       PrintWriter pr = response.getWriter();



       try
       {
           Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
           Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://F://Subjects//WT Netbeans//WT P5//src//studentmis.accdb","","");
           String FirstName = request.getParameter("FName");
           String LastName = request.getParameter("LName");
           String Insert = request.getParameter("Insert");
           String Update = request.getParameter("Update");
           String Delete = request.getParameter("Delete");
           int ID = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("ID"));
           int Age = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("Age"));
           String SqlInsert="INSERT INTO student_info(Firstname,Lastname,ID,Age)VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
           String SqlUpdate="UPDATE student_info SET Lastname=? ID=? Age=? WHERE Firstname=?";
           String SqlDelete="DELETE FROM student_info WHERE Firstname=?";
           if(Insert!=null)
           {
               PreparedStatement InsertStatement = con.prepareStatement(SqlInsert);
               InsertStatement.setString(1,FirstName);
               InsertStatement.setString(2,LastName);
               InsertStatement.setInt(3,ID);
               InsertStatement.setInt(4,Age);
               int RowsInserted = InsertStatement.executeUpdate();
               if(RowsInserted > 0)
                pr.println("New User Added Successfully");

           }

           else if(Update!=null)
           {
               PreparedStatement UpdateStatement = con.prepareStatement(SqlUpdate);
               UpdateStatement.setString(1,FirstName);
               UpdateStatement.setString(2,LastName);
               UpdateStatement.setInt(3,ID);
               UpdateStatement.setInt(4,Age);
               int RowsUpdated = UpdateStatement.executeUpdate();
               if(RowsUpdated > 0)
                pr.println("User Updated Successfully");

           }

           else if(Delete!=null)
           {
               PreparedStatement DeleteStatement = con.prepareStatement(SqlDelete);
               DeleteStatement.setString(1,FirstName);
               int RowsDeleted = DeleteStatement.executeUpdate();
               if(RowsDeleted > 0)
                pr.println("User Updated Successfully");
           }

       } 


       catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) 
       {
           pr.println(ex);
       }

        //processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}

/**
 * Returns a short description of the servlet.
 *
 * @return a String containing servlet description
 */
@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}// </editor-fold>
```

}

After running the project,
If I press the insert button (after entering info) it gives error

```
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.1 user lacks privilege or object not found: FIRSTNAME
```

If I press the delete button (after entering info) it gives error

```
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.1 user lacks privilege or object not found: FIRSTNAME
```

If I press the update button (after entering info) it gives error

```
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.1 user lacks privilege or object not found: LASTNAME
```

This is what my MS Access database `studentmis.accdb` contains :

[image: Database description]

Please help me find the problem in this code. If it's database authentication problem, then I assure that I didn't create a username and password for this database.
Also, I assure that I have imported all the necessary `.jar` files for using Ucanaccess driver.

Ok now the other errors are resolved. Now I'm getting this `errornet.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.1 unexpected token: ID` when i try to click the update button. Modified `MIS.java`

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 *
 * @author Gaurav
 */
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/MIS"})
public class MIS extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet MIS</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet MIS at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
       PrintWriter pr = response.getWriter();



       try
       {
           Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
           Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://F://Subjects//WT Netbeans//WT P5//src//studentmis.accdb");
           String FirstName = request.getParameter("FName");
           String LastName = request.getParameter("LName");
           String Insert = request.getParameter("Insert");
           String Update = request.getParameter("Update");
           String Delete = request.getParameter("Delete");
           int ID = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("ID"));
           int Age = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("Age"));
           String SqlInsert="INSERT INTO student_info(Firstname,Lastname,ID,Age)VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
           String SqlUpdate="UPDATE student_info SET Lastname=? ID=? Age=? WHERE Firstname=?";
           String SqlDelete="DELETE FROM student_info WHERE Firstname=?";
           if(Insert!=null)
           {
               PreparedStatement InsertStatement = con.prepareStatement(SqlInsert);
               InsertStatement.setString(1,FirstName);
               InsertStatement.setString(2,LastName);
               InsertStatement.setInt(3,ID);
               InsertStatement.setInt(4,Age);
               int RowsInserted = InsertStatement.executeUpdate();
               if(RowsInserted > 0)
                pr.println("New User Added Successfully");

           }

           else if(Update!=null)
           {
               PreparedStatement UpdateStatement = con.prepareStatement(SqlUpdate);
               UpdateStatement.setString(1, LastName);
               UpdateStatement.setInt(2,ID);
               UpdateStatement.setInt(3,Age);
               UpdateStatement.setString(4,FirstName);
               int RowsUpdated = UpdateStatement.executeUpdate();
               if(RowsUpdated > 0)
                pr.println("User Updated Successfully");

           }

           else if(Delete!=null)
           {
               PreparedStatement DeleteStatement = con.prepareStatement(SqlDelete);
               DeleteStatement.setString(1,FirstName);
               int RowsDeleted = DeleteStatement.executeUpdate();
               if(RowsDeleted > 0)
                pr.println("User Deleted Successfully");
           }

       } 


       catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) 
       {
           pr.println(ex);
       }

        //processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error because the names of your fields are not correct, the name of your fields are :

```
|  Field1   |   Field1   |  Field3   |   Field4   |
```

and not :

```
|  Firstname |   Lastname   |  ID   |   Age   |
```

In fact `Firstname, Lastname, ID, Age` is values and not names of your columns, so correct the name of your fields and every thing will be ok.

[image: error]

---

**EDIT**

> net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.1 unexpected
>   token: ID

This is logic because you set your attributes in the wrong position :

```
UPDATE student_info SET Lastname=? ID=? Age=? WHERE Firstname=?
//--------------------------1----^--2-^--3--^----------4------^

UpdateStatement.setString(1,FirstName);//<<-----this should be Lastname
UpdateStatement.setString(2,LastName);//<<-----this should be ID
UpdateStatement.setInt(3,ID);//<<-----this should be Age
UpdateStatement.setInt(4,Age);//<<-----this should be Firstname
```

So instead use this :

```
UpdateStatement.setString(1, LastName);
UpdateStatement.setInt(2, ID);
UpdateStatement.setInt(3, Age);
UpdateStatement.setString(4, FirstName);
```

---

**For good practice**

Don't name your variables with Upper Letter in beggining `UpdateStatement`

**EDIT**

You miss the comma between yor fields, the correct syntax for UPDATE is :

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...
WHERE condition;
```

So in your query :

```
UPDATE student_info SET Lastname=? ID=? Age=? WHERE Firstname=?
//--------------------------------^----^--miss comma
```

Instead use:

```
UPDATE student_info SET Lastname=?, ID=?, Age=? WHERE Firstname=?
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was very silly of me. But there's a different error now. Insertion and deletion are working, updating isn't. When I tried pressing the update button, it gave an error `net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.1 unexpected token: ID`. Please tell what maybe the problem @YCF_L

Comment: check my edit @GauravGilalkar you mixed your attributes for that you get this error good luck

Comment: Tried the edit you suggested, isn't working. Still the exact same error. `net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.1 unexpected token: ID` @YCF_L

Comment: are you sure @GauravGilalkar maybe you changed the the if Insert block, check again if not post your code that you change it

Comment: Yes, I changed the correct block. But I can't post the code here in comment. It says comment too long. I'll modify the question instead @YCF_L

Comment: post your code please @GauravGilalkar you can edit your question

Comment: @GauravGilalkar did you clean and re-deploy your project after your edit? maybe its good also to restart your server and your JVM, try this and let me know

Comment: Did clean and build and run the project again. Restarted the server. Same error. @YCF_L

Comment: You miss the comma between your field @GauravGilalkar check my edit now

Comment: Damn I missed such a small thing. It's working now.  Thanks a lot @YCF_L for being with me patiently for such a long time.

Comment: Is it ok if I get your contact info (preferrably email id) in case I get any further queries in the future ?

Comment: you can find me here in stack-overflow @GauravGilalkar always so this is my home, if that help you have to accept the answer [validate answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/344497) good luck

Comment: If that's the case then it's ok. Validated your answer. Thanks a lot...!!!